# Error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority, kind cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running into a strange issue, docker pull works but when using kubectl create or apply -f  with kind cluster, it is getting below error

```
  Warning  Failed     20m                   kubelet, kind-control-plane  Failed to pull image "quay.io/airshipit/kubernetes-entrypoint:v1.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "quay.io/airshipit/kubernetes-entrypoint:v1.0.0": failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get https://d3uo42mtx6z2cr.cloudfront.net/sha256/b5/b554c0d094dd848c822804a164c7eb9cc3d41db5f2f5d2fd47aba54454d95daf?Expires=1587558576&Signature=Tt9R1O4K5zI6hFG9GYt-tLAWkwlQyLoAF0NDNouFnff2ywZnPlMSo2x2aopKcQJ5cAMYYTHvYBKm2Zwk8W80tE9cRet1PfP6CnAmo2lzsYzKnRRWbgQhgsyJK8AmAvKzw7iw6lbYdP91JjEiUcpfjMAj7dMPj97tpnEnnd72kljRew8VfgBhClblnhNFvfR9fs9lRS7wNFKrZ1WUSGpNEEJZjNcc9zBNIbOyKeDPfvIpdJ6OthQMJ3EKaFEFfVN6asiyz3lOgM2IMjJ0uBI2ChhCyDx7YHTdNZCOoYAEmw8zo5Ma0n8EQpX3EwU1qSR0IwoGNawF0qV6tFAZi5lpbQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJ67PQLWGCSP66DGA: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Here is the ./kube/config

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://127.0.0.1:32768
  name: kind-kind
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-kind
    user: kind-kind
  name: kind-kind
current-context: kind-kind
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-kind
  user:
    client-certificate-data: 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
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQpNSUlFcEFJQkFBS0NBUUVBMCtnQkpYcGlSdzErT1ZoYVY1NGxuSDJ3R080TCtYSGYwZ1IxWnVNNTJ1MFBVd0x0CjlwM0J3Z3lYNUc4OGdxQUgyaHcrVzhTaVhSL1ZRQzkySXdyd3J3NWxZZnE0a1g2YVhHMXRWS0YxbFNiTFB3eDYKTi96MUxzOWtueVFvamIwd1dmRnZ1Qms5S0IyMm5JWjNnTlBGWVZjVXFsMjNrN3JOci9Mc3RmZ3BCaFU0WmFncwpsKzJkbndCWXYxWHhnUzVQYW5MbFRwVVg4MjFndHNDRG1DdWhRckJUM3c2dDV5alFOTEhja2dzOGNSV1JHcWRTCmdkYyt0a1hzOTM0N2hLNGNrN0dhTDQ4cUExODNnMFcrTWRJZXA0d01MRm1PV0wrRktkOXQvN216TG4yeUVnbEUKeW82MWlRZGZXazVLZDVzUGpBS1VleVZVMitONUFKUEt3cGhhclFJREFRQUJBb0lCQUZzYWsrT1pDa2VoOVhLUwpHY1V4cU5udTc1YklRVDJ0UjV6emJjWWVTdkZrbWdJR2NHaG15cmF5MDFyU3VDRXd6QzlwbFNXL0ZFOFZNSW0zCjNnS1M0WWRobVJUV3hpTkhXdllCMWM5YzIwQ1V2UzBPSUQyUjg1ZDhjclk0eFhhcXIrNzdiaHlvUFRMU0U0Q1kKRHlqRDQwaEdPQXhHM25ZVkNmbHJaM21VaDQ2bEo4YlROcXB5UzFCcVdNZnZwekt1ZDB6TElmMWtTTW9Cbm1XeQo0RzBrNC9qWVdEOWNwdGtSTGxvZXp5WVlCMTRyOVdNQjRENkQ5eE84anhLL0FlOEQraTl2WCtCaUdGOURSYllJCmVVQmRTQzE2QnQybW5XWGhXMmhSRFFqRmR2dzJIQ0gxT0ppcVZuWUlwbGJEcjFYVXI1NzFYWTZQMFJlQ0JRc3kKOUZpMG44RUNnWUVBMUQ3Nmlobm5YaEZyWFE2WkVEWnp3ZGlwcE5mbHExMGJxV0V5WUVVZmpPd2p3ZnJ4bzVEYgppUmoySm5Fei96bDhpVDFEbmh3bFdWZlBNbWo3bUdFMVYwMkFWSkJoT20vdU1tZnhYVmcvWGwxOVEzODdJT0tpCjBKSmdabGZqVjEyUGdRU3NnbnRrckdJa3dPcisrOUFaL3R0UVVkVlU0bFgxWWRuazZ5T1V6YWNDZ1lFQS81Y1kKcHJxMVhuNGZBTUgxMzZ2dVhDK2pVaDhkUk9xS1Zia2ZtWUw0dkI0dG9jL2N1c1JHaGZPaTZmdEZCSngwcDhpSgpDU1ZCdzIxbmNHeGRobDkwNkVjZml2ZG0vTXJlSmlyQmFlMlRRVWdsMjh1cmU3MWJEdXpjbWMrQVRQa1VXVDgyCmJpaDM5b3A1SEo5N2NlU3JVYU5zRTgxaEdIaXNSSzJEL2pCTjU0c0NnWUVBcUExeHJMVlQ5NnlOT1BKZENYUkQKOWFHS3VTWGxDT2xCQkwwYitSUGlKbCsyOUZtd3lGVGpMc3RmNHhKUkhHMjFDS2xFaDhVN1lXRmdna2FUcDVTWQplcGEzM0wwdzd1Yy9VQlB6RFhqWk8rdUVTbFJNU2Y2SThlSmtoOFJoRW9UWElrM0VGZENENXVZU3VkbVhxV1NkCm9LaWdFUnQ4Q1hZTVE3MFdQNFE5eHhNQ2dZQnBkVTJ0bGNJNkQrMzQ0UTd6VUR5VWV1OTNkZkVjdTIyQ3UxU24KZ1p2aCtzMjNRMDMvSGZjL1UreTNnSDdVelQxdzhWUmhtcWJNM1BwZUw4aFRKbFhWZFdzMWFxbHF5c1hvbDZHZwpkRzlhODByenF0REJ5THFtcU9MSThBNHZOR0xLQkVRUUpkQ0J3RmNDa1dkYzhnNGlMRHp1MnNJaVY4QTB3aWVCCkhTczN5d0tCZ1FDeXl2Tk45enk5S3dNOW1nMW5GMlh3WUVzMzB4bmsrNXJmTGdRMzQvVm1sSVA5Y1cyWS9oTWQKWnVlNWd4dnlYREcrZW9GU3Njc281TmcwLytWUDI0Sjk0cGJIcFJWV3FIWENvK2gxZjBnKzdET2p0dWp2aGVBRwpSb240NmF1clJRSG5HUStxeldWcWtpS2l1dDBybFpHd2ZzUGs4eWptVjcrWVJuamxES1hUWUE9PQotLS0tLUVORCBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQo=
```

Comment: that kubeconfig file is what is being used by kubelet? where did u get it from?

Comment: this gets created with kind installation

Comment: share content of /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf from the nodes

Comment: cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
cat: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf: No such file or directory
There is no such file, since this is kind cluster, it behaves differently, how, not really sure

Comment: is kubelet running on that node? How did u setup the kind cluster? docs? you can put the other Kubecong file at /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf and restart kubelet

Comment: I checked with Internal IT team today and they are working on fixing these kind of issues with proxy, it is a known issue as per them

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue (I think) on OpenShift - I could pull images, but I couldn't push or get k8s to pull them. To resolve it, I had to update the docker config at `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and add the registry as an insecure registry. For openshift, the default route was required.

```
OPTIONS=' <some existing config stuff here> --insecure-registry=<fqdn-of-your-registry>'
```

Then `systemctl restart docker` to have the changes take effect.

You might also need to create a docker pull secret with your credentials in kubernetes to allow it to access the registry. Details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)